# How can I get column names from PDOStatement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've recently built a class for automatic paging and ordering of query results, that works with PDO.

Here's how I retrieve the data from a MySQL table:

```
$this->query = "SELECT _id, name, price, creationDate, isPublished FROM fruits";
$this->fetch_type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
$this->result = $db->query($this->query);
$this->rows = $this->result->fetchAll($this->fetch_type);
$this->columns = empty($this->rows) ? array() : array_keys($this->rows[0]);
```

This way I can easily store the column names inside an array (that's exactly what I need):

```
var_dump($this->columns):

array
  0 => string '_id' (length=3)
  1 => string 'name' (length=4)
  2 => string 'price' (length=5)
  3 => string 'creationDate' (length=12)
  4 => string 'isPublished' (length=11)
```

However, my method doesn't work if the fetch type is `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, since I'm no more working with 2D arrays, but with objects inside arrays:

```
var_dump($this->rows):

array
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[11]
  public '_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'name' => string 'apple' (length=5)
  public 'price' => string '26.00' (length=5)
  public 'creationDate' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'isPublished' => string '1' (length=1)
 1 => 
object(stdClass)[12]
  public '_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'name' => string 'banana' (length=11)
  public 'price' => string '15.00' (length=5)
  public 'creationDate' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'isPublished' => string '1' (length=1)
 2 => 
object(stdClass)[13]
  public '_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'name' => string 'orange' (length=6)
  public 'price' => string '12.12' (length=5)
  public 'creationDate' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'isPublished' => string '1' (length=1)

  etc...
```

So, how can I get column names from a result like this above?

Comment: Architecturally it might be more appropriate for the layer which created the query to know which fields it requested and how they were aliased. But as a simpler solution, [`array_keys(get_object_vars($this->rows[0]))`](http://us.php.net/get_object_vars) should work.

Comment: @DCoder `(array)` cast is better because it does the same job but will not break if you do it to something that is already an array. So you don't have to evaluate `$this->fetch_type` to determine what to do, it will always just work.

Comment: @DaveRandom  your cast does useless job and wastes memory / cpu cycles ;p A simple check will be more effective: `array_keys(is_object($this->rows[0]) ? get_object_vars($this->rows[0]) : $this->rows[0])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer to this is to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the item that you pass to `array_keys()` to an explicit `(array)` - that way, arrays are unaffected but objects become the correct type:

```
$this->columns = empty($this->rows) ? array() : array_keys((array) $this->rows[0]);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution won't work if you receive an empty result set.

Answer (score 5):

[getColumnMeta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) can retrieve the name of a column, it returns an associative array containing amongst others the obvious "name" key.

so

```
$meta = $this->result->getColumnMeta(0); // 0 indexed so 0 would be first column
$name = $meta['name'];
```

Comment: getColumnMeta is experimental feature, you can't rely on it

Comment: in 2022, getColumnMeta() is no longer experimental and is implemented for all PDO drivers listed in the php doc.